# Python inserting dynamic list in excel file

Tags: excel, list, python-3.x, pandas

My program compares the values in two files that are loaded dynamically every month. The value in between may vary every time. The first file has to be the same as the second one. If my script finds something that doesn't match, it will save these values in a list. If it finds more than one missmatch it appends it to the list of values like this:

```
  ['001210', '13/06/2016', '000590030', '0', '16', '16105971', '26-  -  ',
   '001210', '13/06/2016', '000590030', '0', '16', '16105971', '26-  -  ', 
   'VW0012', '13/06/2016', '000590030', '0', '16', '16105971', '26-  -  ',
   'VW0012', '13/06/2016', '000590030', '0', '16', '16105971', '26-  -  ']
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write the output like this:

Columns divided like the code formatted above and the number of rows that changes it's range...
What can I do?
It's better pandas or what?

Any advice is precious...

Thank you in advance

The Output should look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Code |    Date  |   ID    | Qty In |  Qty Out | DDT    |    Wk  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|001210|13/06/2016|000590030|      0 |       16 |16105971|26-  -  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|001210|13/06/2016|000590030|      0 |       16 |16105971|26-  -  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|VW0012|13/06/2016|000590030|      0 |       16 |16105971|26-  -  |
```

And so on... Every new match, is a new row in excel output file...

Comment: this is really broad, you've not posted what the 2 files look like or your attempts at this problem, could you post a few lines of the files that you want to compare

Comment: But, I've only to write to excel this list divided by column and row like the output above... At this point the files are already compared.

Comment: Can you post the desired output like how it should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way with Pandas.
I've divided every list in a single list and then passed to pandas like this:

```
excelResult = pd.DataFrame({'Imballo': imballoColumn,
                            'Data': dateColumn,
                            'Abs/Empfae': absColumn,
                            'Quantità in entrata': inColumn,
                            'Quantità in uscita': outColumn,
                            'Numero Bolla': ddtColumn,
                            'WK-LG-LR': wkColumn})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('theResult.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
excelResult.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='mismatching')
writer.save()
```